# How do I get around int value resetting after changing method

Tags: c#

I set an int value in my method `GetDays`, I then want to use this value inside `GetRiskAssement()` but it changes to default 0 as soon as I return back to this method.

I want to set `intDays` and for it to stay the same until I run the `GetDays` method again.

```
public class RiskA
{
    int accountId;
    static int intDays;
    bool stop;
    List<int> DateVehicleList = new List<int>();

    public List<DisplayableRiskAssement> DisplayableRiskAssement { get; private set; }

    public RiskAssement()
    {
        accountId = 461;
        DisplayableRiskAssement = GetRiskAssement();
    }

    List<DisplayableRiskAssement> GetRiskAssement()
    {
       //Additional code here than runs through a load of records
        if(riskAssement.InUK == false)
        {
            GetVehiclesNotInUK(riskAssement.VehicleID);
            riskAssement.IntDaysSinceUK = intDays;
        }
        return riskAssesments;
    }

    protected void GetVehiclesNotInUK(int VehicleID) 
    {
        //Code here that creates DateVehicleList
        GetDays(DateVehicleList, intDays);
    }

    private static int GetDays(List<int> DateVehicleList, int intDays) 
    {
        using (aEntities db = new aEntities())
        {
            foreach (var item in DateVehicleList)
            {
                var qryDate = (from a in db.ev
                               where a.evID == item
                               select a.sysdatetime).Single();

                string strDate = qryDate.ToString();
                DateTime oldDate = DateTime.Parse(strDate);

                TimeSpan t = DateTime.Now - oldDate;
                double doubleDays = t.TotalDays;
                intDays = Convert.ToInt32(doubleDays);
            }
        }
        DateVehicleList.Clear();
        return intDays;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is because you don't saving value in static int intDays, instead of you save it in your input/output parameter which have same name.

Comment: Renaming your input parameter `int intDays` on method `GetDays()` will solve your issue.

Comment: to solve your problem either change name of this variable, or just use: 
`intDays = GetDays(DateVehicleList, intDays);` or use `ref`/ `out` ward. 
But best way would be to change variable's name because it's little confusing

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it @croxy

Answer (score 0):

Your method `GetDays` should operate on class variables, not on parameters that you are passing.

If you expect the method to use class variables, just remove parameters from this method:

```
private static int GetDays(){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#, arguments can be passed to parameters either by value or by reference. For your **GetDays** method you have passed *DateVehicleList* by reference and *intDays* by value. Your previous *intDays* value from class object will not be updated unless you assign the returned value in it.

```
protected void GetVehiclesNotInUK(int VehicleID) 
{
    //Code here that creates DateVehicleList
    intDays = GetDays(DateVehicleList, intDays);
}
```

not it will work as of you intended, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

int is of Primitive type so by default it is 0. So when your object is initialized, your constructor calls GetRiskAssement() method and that method used intDay that's not still set in your GetDays() method that's why it returns 0 to you.
You can use intDay as your class attribute and make getter and setter of it, and your getDays() method works on your class attributes rather than parameters.

```
private static int intDay;
public static int getIntDay()
{
    return intDay;
}
public static void setIntDay(int intDay)
{
    this.intDay = intDay;
}
```

and your function should looks like.

```
private static int GetDays()
{
    //your code goes here
}
```

hope this helps you.